# Can I put a 512GB sd card in my Xiaomi Redmi Note 8?

Tags: external-sd, sd-card, xiaomi

I bought a 512GB sd card but right after I investigated the characteristics of the Redmi Note 8, and everywhere it says that it supports up to 256GB memory, I got frustrated but still I inserted the memory to see what happened.

I was curious, but it did not happen nothing out of the ordinary, he accepted it, so it seems suspicious to me. If I leave it inside, do you think it will have an impact on my cell phone?

Comment: guess in the time of writing specifications there was only 256 gb available on market, but it can handle 512 gb as well

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/lsr4ze/if_my_phone_has_a_max_sd_capacity_of_256gb_can_i